# Can I use "einer" in the sentence below instead of "eine"

Tags: pronoun

Durch die teilweise automatisch abgewickelte Bestellung müssen immer weniger Mitarbeiter in den Firmen beschäftigt werden und durch die Unterstützung in Form von Computern kann **eine** noch höhere Anzahl von Vorgängen bearbeitet werden.

I think **eine** in this sentence is [indefinite pronoun](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/german-easy-learning/what-are-the-german-indefinite-pronouns) (correct me if I'm wrong), so we can also use the masculine form of the word (einer).

Comment: The idea to swap a female article against a masculine one seems adventurous; I can' t come up with an example, where this is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot: "eine" in that sentence is an indefinite article for the word "Anzahl", which is a feminine noun. The gender of the article needs to agree with the gender of the noun it refers to, hence the feminine article "eine" must be used.